# Storing the lowest level bits and returning a char

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation

I'm working on an assignment that decodes a secret message stored in a PPM format picture. The first thing i need to do is find the length of the message, which is hidden in a single byte spread across the first 8 data bytes of the picture. After I have this, my logic is to create a method where I have a loop that shifts the bits 7 spots, records the first one, and when there are 8 bits, return the char that they represent. 
So right now I'm trying to understand how this would work. 
I was trying to get the value for the length of the hidden message. 
I tried to do this manually to see how all the bits behaved.

```
fgets(str,64,fp);
char length[7];
length[0] = str[7];
length[1] =  str[15];
length[2] = str[23];
length[3] = str[31];
length[4] = str[39];
length[5] = str[47];
length[6] =  str[55];
length[7] = str[63];
printf(length);
```

So since the length is hidden in the lowest level bit of 8 bytes i used fgets(str,64,fp); and then stored each 8th value in an array. This returns "enpm0dp".
When I changed the array to int, the output was an arrow.

Can someone explain to me how to store bits into a byte and then return the char that corresponds to this value? Do i use an array of 8 bits? or store them in a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to think that `fgets()` counts length in bits (64 for 8 bytes), but it really doesn't; it counts in characters.  See [the documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).

Next, you seem to think that `str` is ana rray of bits, but arrays of bits don't exist like that in C.

You're going to have to consider an array of characters, which we'll assume is bytes:

```
unsigned char str[8];

if(fgets(str, sizeof str, fp))
{
  unsigned char length = 0, i;

  for(i = 0; i < sizeof str; ++i)
  {
    length >>= 1;
    length |= str[i] & 0x80;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to C, and trying to understand how exactly this works before trying to apply it. What does the body of the for loop do?